# Drupal 7: Separating content edit screen in tabs

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, display-suite

If you are familiar with drupal 7, you will remember there are some tabs at top right of edit screen of contents. I want to separate my content into those kind of tabs. Because I have numerous field collections in my content and they all have more than 100 entries. My client, obviously, doesn't want to wait for a long time just to change a text part in that content.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout below modules might help you

1. https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group
2. https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields

Cheers!!!

Comment: Unfortunately they are just html5 tabs. Even pagegroup widget is not making a network call. So, nothing changes about performance, you still have to wait.

Comment: You can try combination of View and quick tab module. Quick tab has option to load content on click. Also using editable fields you can edit content on fly.

Comment: With field group, there's an option for horizontal tab groups and horizontal tabs. This enables jQuery UI tabs for node edit fields. We do this all the time with large content types so that on node edit, you can switch from tab to tab without a page reload.